# Sequelize: Ordering inside association

Tags: sorting, sequelize.js, associations

**MODELS**

**product.js**

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Product = sequelize.define(
        "Product",
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            title: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(80),
                allowNull: true,
            },
        },
        {
            tableName: "product",
        },
    );

    Product.associate = function(models) {
        Product.hasMany(models.ProductPrice, { foreignKey: "product_id" });
    };
    return Product;
};
```

**product-price.js**

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var ProductPrice = sequelize.define(
        "ProductPrice",
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            product_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            price: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: true,
            }
        },
        {
            tableName: "product_price",
        },
    );
    ProductPrice.associate = function(models) {
        ProductPrice.belongsTo(models.Product, { foreignKey: "product_id" });
    };
    return ProductPrice;
};
```

I'm trying to fetch the latest price from the `ProductPrice` table using **two** kinds of ordering.

1. The ordering of the associated returned prices of a product (single product `have many` prices) - Sorting in Descending order On `id` to get the latest price, with `limit:1`.
2. Then re-ordering of the multiple products by price
   I am trying to query the most recent price and then order the multiple products whether in ascending or descending order.

**Code that produces error**

```js
models.Product.findAndCountAll({
  //THIS LINE PRODUCES ERROR
  order: [[models.ProductPrice, "price", "DESC"]],
  include: [
    //BRINGS THE CORRECT LATEST PRICE
    { model: models.ProductPrice, order: [["id", "DESC"]], limit:1 },
  ]
})
  .then(data=>{
    res.json({data.rows})
  }
```

**Error**

> SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'ProductPrices.price' in 'order
>   clause'

Note: Ignore that I am using `findAndCountAll` - unless that is the issue?

Comment: Please add your `Product` and `ProductPrice` model definitions

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use order after include, like this

```
models.Product.findAndCountAll({
  include: [
     //BRINGS THE CORRECT LATEST PRICE
     { model: models.ProductPrice, order: [["id", "DESC"]], limit:1 },
  ]   
  //THIS LINE PRODUCES ERROR
  order: [models.ProductPrice, "price", "DESC"],
})
.then(data=>{
    res.json({data.rows})
}
```

for more reference, [eagerly-loaded-models](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models),

**edit**
lines copied from official doc

```
Company.findAll({ include: [ Division ], order: [ [ Division, 'name' ] ] });
```

Comment: It would have been really stupid if this would have worked. Nevertheless, no change in the queries.

Comment: just visit the link of official doc that i have given, and for the order to work on the association model you must include that association first..